# Is it possible to create table using insert (select, update, delete)?

Tags: sql-server, create-table

Due to some restrictions I am able to use SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE. Is it possible to bypass *CREATE TABLE* using this?

I found the system tables and system views: **sys.objects**, **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS**

So it is possible to simulate this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
column_name1 data_type(size),
column_name2 data_type(size),
column_name3 data_type(size)
);
```

by using something like this:

```
INSERT INTO INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS (TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE) 
VALUES ('dbo','table_name','column_name1','data_type');
INSERT INTO INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS (TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE) 
VALUES ('dbo','table_name','column_name2','data_type');
INSERT INTO INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS (TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE) 
VALUES ('dbo','table_name','column_name3','data_type');
```

?

I am afraid that **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** is view and not a table but I hope there will be some way to do it.

Comment: Even if it were possible to `INSERT` into `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, it would be a very bad idea.

Comment: What would be the point in not having permission to create and being able to bypass it?

Comment: @DavidG I could not agree more.

Comment: @juergend I am calling it from programming environment which has native support for SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE but I can not find a native way for anything else (like create or alter table). If it will be possible it will make time needed for creating tables much faster. Otherwise we will need to call some external program or method and create it in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select '1' as column_name1 ,'Anand' as column_name2 ,'3' as column_name3 into table_name
```

This creates the table `table_name`.  but the data length is used as the values specified.so first column gets varchar(1) and 2nd column gets varchar(5)

Comment: Is it way how to alter or delete table in this style?

Comment: I don't think so we have one

Comment: Deleting or altering a table has many attributes to check for example a foreign key,not null etc., so its not a good idea to bypass that and create a untrusted/unusable structure.